# How to build a custom question-answering head when using hugginface transformers?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

Using the `TFBertForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained()` function, we get a predefined head on top of BERT together with a loss function that are suitable for this task.

My question is how to create a custom head without relying on `TFAutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained()`.

I want to do this because there is no place where the architecture of the head is explained clearly. By reading the code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/198c335d219a5eb4d3f124fdd1ce1a9cd9f78a9b/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_tf_bert.py#L2065) we can see the architecture they are using, but I can't be sure I understand their code 100%.

Starting from [How to Fine-tune HuggingFace BERT model for Text Classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69025750/how-to-fine-tune-huggingface-bert-model-for-text-classificationis) is good. However, it covers only the classification task, which is much simpler.

`'start_positions'` and `'end_positions'` are created following [this](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/7?fw=pt) tutorial.

So far, I've got the following:

```
train_dataset
# Dataset({
#     features: ['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask', 'start_positions', 'end_positions'],
#     num_rows: 99205
# })
train_dataset.set_format(type='tensorflow', columns=['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask'])
features = {x: train_dataset[x] for x in ['input_ids', 'token_type_ids', 'attention_mask']}
labels = [train_dataset[x] for x in ['start_positions', 'end_positions']]
labels = np.array(labels).T
tfdataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels)).batch(16)

input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids')
token_type_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,), dtype=tf.int32, name='token_type_ids')
attention_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input((256,), dtype=tf.int32, name='attention_mask')


bert = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
output = bert([input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask]).last_hidden_state
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, name="qa_outputs")(output)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask], outputs=output)


num_train_epochs = 3
num_train_steps = len(tfdataset) * num_train_epochs
optimizer, schedule = create_optimizer(
   init_lr=2e-5,
   num_warmup_steps=0,
   num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
   weight_decay_rate=0.01
)

def qa_loss(labels, logits):
    loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
        from_logits=True, reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE
    )
    start_loss = loss_fn(labels[0], logits[0])
    end_loss = loss_fn(labels[1], logits[1])
    return (start_loss + end_loss) / 2.0


model.compile(
    loss=loss_fn,
    optimizer=optimizer
)

model.fit(tfdataset, epochs=num_train_epochs)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(2,) and logits.shape=(256, 2)
```

It is complaining about the shape of the labels. This should not happen since I am using `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I actually found a solution, which is just editing the TFBertForQuestionAnswering class itself. For example, I added an additional layer in the following code and trained the model as usual and it worked.

```
from transformers import TFBertPreTrainedModel
from transformers import TFBertMainLayer
from transformers.modeling_tf_utils import TFQuestionAnsweringLoss, get_initializer, input_processing
from transformers.modeling_tf_outputs import TFQuestionAnsweringModelOutput 
from transformers import BertConfig

class MY_TFBertForQuestionAnswering(TFBertPreTrainedModel, TFQuestionAnsweringLoss):
    # names with a '.' represents the authorized unexpected/missing layers when a TF model is loaded from a PT model
    _keys_to_ignore_on_load_unexpected = [
        r"pooler",
        r"mlm___cls",
        r"nsp___cls",
        r"cls.predictions",
        r"cls.seq_relationship",
    ]

    def __init__(self, config: BertConfig, *inputs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(config, *inputs, **kwargs)

        self.num_labels = config.num_labels

        self.bert = TFBertMainLayer(config, add_pooling_layer=False, name="bert")

        # This is the dense layer I added 
        self.my_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=config.hidden_size,
            kernel_initializer=get_initializer(config.initializer_range),
            name="my_dense",
        )
        self.qa_outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            units=config.num_labels,
            kernel_initializer=get_initializer(config.initializer_range),
            name="qa_outputs",
        )

    def call(
        self,
        input_ids = None,
        attention_mask = None,
        token_type_ids = None,
        position_ids = None,
        head_mask = None,
        inputs_embeds = None,
        output_attentions = None,
        output_hidden_states = None,
        return_dict = None,
        start_positions = None,
        end_positions= None,
        training = False,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        r"""
        start_positions (`tf.Tensor` or `np.ndarray` of shape `(batch_size,)`, *optional*):
            Labels for position (index) of the start of the labelled span for computing the token classification loss.
            Positions are clamped to the length of the sequence (`sequence_length`). Position outside of the sequence
            are not taken into account for computing the loss.
        end_positions (`tf.Tensor` or `np.ndarray` of shape `(batch_size,)`, *optional*):
            Labels for position (index) of the end of the labelled span for computing the token classification loss.
            Positions are clamped to the length of the sequence (`sequence_length`). Position outside of the sequence
            are not taken into account for computing the loss.
        """
        inputs = input_processing(
            func=self.call,
            config=self.config,
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
            position_ids=position_ids,
            head_mask=head_mask,
            inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
            output_attentions=output_attentions,
            output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
            return_dict=return_dict,
            start_positions=start_positions,
            end_positions=end_positions,
            training=training,
            kwargs_call=kwargs,
        )
        outputs = self.bert(
            input_ids=inputs["input_ids"],
            attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"],
            token_type_ids=inputs["token_type_ids"],
            position_ids=inputs["position_ids"],
            head_mask=inputs["head_mask"],
            inputs_embeds=inputs["inputs_embeds"],
            output_attentions=inputs["output_attentions"],
            output_hidden_states=inputs["output_hidden_states"],
            return_dict=inputs["return_dict"],
            training=inputs["training"],
        )
        sequence_output = outputs[0]

        # You also have to add it here
        my_logits = self.my_dense(inputs=sequence_output)
        logits = self.qa_outputs(inputs=my_logits)
        start_logits, end_logits = tf.split(value=logits, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=-1)
        start_logits = tf.squeeze(input=start_logits, axis=-1)
        end_logits = tf.squeeze(input=end_logits, axis=-1)
        loss = None

        if inputs["start_positions"] is not None and inputs["end_positions"] is not None:
            labels = {"start_position": inputs["start_positions"]}
            labels["end_position"] = inputs["end_positions"]
            loss = self.hf_compute_loss(labels=labels, logits=(start_logits, end_logits))

        if not inputs["return_dict"]:
            output = (start_logits, end_logits) + outputs[2:]
            return ((loss,) + output) if loss is not None else output

        return TFQuestionAnsweringModelOutput(
            loss=loss,
            start_logits=start_logits,
            end_logits=end_logits,
            hidden_states=outputs.hidden_states,
            attentions=outputs.attentions,
        )

    def serving_output(self, output: TFQuestionAnsweringModelOutput) -> TFQuestionAnsweringModelOutput:
        hs = tf.convert_to_tensor(output.hidden_states) if self.config.output_hidden_states else None
        attns = tf.convert_to_tensor(output.attentions) if self.config.output_attentions else None

        return TFQuestionAnsweringModelOutput(
            start_logits=output.start_logits, end_logits=output.end_logits, hidden_states=hs, attentions=attns
        )
```